# HttpURLConnection Character Encoding

Tags: java, encoding, httpurlconnection

I'm making a simple program. 
There is a url with using charset "utf-8". 
I want to get whole source from this page, 
but there is character encoding problem.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

class WholeTest {

    HttpURLConnection conn;


    public void openUrl() throws Exception {

        URL pageUrl = new URL("http://naver.com");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)pageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "naver.com");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println("---result---");
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
}


public class Whole {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Test");

        WholeTest w = new WholeTest();
        w.openUrl();
    }

}
```

The result is : 
??????????????????????????????????????????????????
I can't view the source. I used charset "utf-8" when reading inputStream, what I did incorrectly?

I use all utf-8, UTF-8, euc-kr, EUC-KR 
...
same result.

Comment: try "UTF-8" instead of utf-8

Comment: The html web is tagged as utf-8 but it is korean. In order to print via system.out, try to specify the correct charset for korean 
  `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "EUC-KR");
   out.println(response.toString());`

Comment: @Raghuveer hmm...same result. I don't know what is the problem. another program is working well. T.T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as I suspected, comment or remove the below line. It will work like a charm.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
```

You are expecting gzip binary when the return is actually `text/html`

Comment: I have specified the reason in the edit. You are expecting a gzip binary format when the return is actually text/html